# Having trouble just getting the Highchart to show

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm pretty new to Javascript, Rails and JQuery all working together.

I'm going through this tutorial (http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use#installation) on Highcharts and just trying to get a base graph to show. It's not happening.

In my home.html.erb file I have:

> `<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>`

In `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` I have this in my `head` tag:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/public/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And this is the code in /public/highcharts.js:

```
var chart1; // globally available
$(document).ready(function() {
      chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
         chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
         },
         title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
         },
         xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
         },
         yAxis: {
            title: {
               text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
         },
         series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
         }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
         }]
      });
   });
```

Nothing is showing up when I load the page and I have no idea why. I've done the tutorial 3 or 4 times and Googled around for the answer to no avail. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Edit: I changed the path in the script tag from `/public/highcharts.js` to `/highcharts.js`. That gave me the following errors in my Console Debugger:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined highcharts.js:3
(anonymous function) highcharts.js:3
f.Callbacks.n jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B
```

Comment: the path to the JS should be `highcharts.js` without the public part. BTW, Rails helpers like `javascript_include_tag` won't find it in the root of the public directory.  If you want to use that helper, you would want it in `./public/javascripts` or `./app/assets/javascripts` depending on the version of rails you are using.

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors in the debugger console in your browser?

Comment: @Brian the only place that the path to highcharts.js is referenced is in the head tag of `application.html.erb`, as I mentioned above

Comment: yes, sorry, I just realized that & edited my comment.

Comment: @WyattAnderson I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/public/highcharts.js`

Comment: you need to include the highcharts js lib too...

Comment: @Brian I believe that I did? Isn't that the script above of the one I just edited?

Comment: you are referencing your script that calls highcharts, not the highcharts library.

Comment: @Brian where would I find the Highcharts library?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13020/discussion-between-brian-and-zack-shapiro)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we discussed in chat, there were a few missing pieces.

- You needed a local copy of the Highcharts library
- You needed to reference your script that calls the library from the
  correct place.

So, in short, you needed this in your layout:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!--where you put the high charts library -->
<script src="/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- your script -->
```

Now going forward (assuming you are working w/ rails 3.1+), I'd suggest moving your javascripts to a more *conventional* location.  In 3.1, rails likes to see it in `app/assets/javascripts`  but `public/javascripts` is still fine, just not exactly *conventional*.

You will get a lot of milage by understanding the [rails helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#asset-tag-helpers) to insert script tags and the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help, Brian!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the first line of source that is `var charts;`  remove it and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the Chart keyword. Please change like

new Highcharts.Chart({  Chart is with small c