# HighCharts is not defined

Tags: javascript, extjs, highcharts

Hi I have a simple MVC extjs application :

My app.js :

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths : {
        'Chart' : './Chart'
    }
});

Ext.require('Chart.ux.Highcharts');
Ext.require('Chart.ux.Highcharts.Serie');
Ext.require('Chart.ux.Highcharts.SplineSerie');

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyAppli',
    autoCreateViewport: true,
});
```

My Controller :

```
showWindow: function () {

    var chartStore = this.getHighChartDataStore();
    var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        width : 800,
        height : 600,
        minHeight : 400,
        minWidth : 550,
        hidden : false,
        shadow : false,
        maximizable : true,
        collapsible: true,
        title : 'Highchart example',
        renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
        layout : 'fit',
        items : [{
            xtype : 'highchart',
            id : 'chart',
            defaultSerieType : 'spline',
            series : [{
                    dataIndex : 'yesterday',
                    name : 'Yesterday',
                    visible : true
                }, {
                    dataIndex : 'today',
                    name : 'Today',
                    visible : true
            }],
            store : chartStore,
            xField : 'time',
            chartConfig : {
                chart : {
                    type: 'spline',
                    marginRight : 130,
                    marginBottom : 120,
                    zoomType : 'x',
                    animation : {
                        duration : 1500,
                        easing : 'swing'
                    }
                },
                title : {
                    text : 'Standalone Highcharts for ExtJs 4 example',
                    x : -20 //center
                },
                subtitle : {
                    text : 'Random value',
                    x : -20
                },
                xAxis : [{
                    title : {
                        text : 'Time',
                        margin : 20
                    },
                    labels : {
                        rotation : 270,
                        y : 35
                    }
                }],
                yAxis : {
                    title : {
                        text : 'Value'
                    },
                    plotLines : [{
                        value : 0,
                        width : 1,
                        color : '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                plotOptions : {
                    series : {
                        animation : {
                            duration : 3000,
                            easing : 'swing'
                        }
                    }
                },       
                legend : {
                    layout : 'vertical',
                    align : 'right',
                    verticalAlign : 'top',
                    x : -10,
                    y : 100,
                    borderWidth : 0
                }
            }
        }]
    });
    win.show();
}
```

My problem is that the above function shows an empty window, while the console says : 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined` in the file `highcharts.js` on the function `draw`.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Extjs 4.1 with the latest HighChart (taken from github).

My index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/view/combo_release.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Chart/ux/highcharts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML that is referencing your JS files?

Comment: Please, show us the code in the files you required.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198568/having-trouble-just-getting-the-highchart-to-show has similar issues. You are most likely missing some pieces

Comment: I did as the link says, downloaded the library and referenced the highcharts.js file but still the same error, ` <script src="highcharts_lib/js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Is this working for you now? Can you please help me as well? :) Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to include jquery (or another supported js library) as well before you call the highcharts.js resource.

Comment: I'm using EXTJS, why should I add JQuery?

Comment: Because HC does not natively work with ExtJS. You may need to use this one: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?93669-Highcharts-adapter-and-plugin-for-ExtJS.

Answer (score 1):

First you should include `highcharts.js` **before** your `app.js`. Secondly looks like you should include `highstock.js` prior to `highcharts.js` also.